# How to get alternating background colour for records in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports

I am displaying records in alternating colour like grey and white. But, I am suppressing some records, for example suppressing a white background record and then the next record is gray so I end up getting gray colour for two records.

Below is the code used in the section for alternating colour.

```
iif (RecordNumber mod 2 = 1, crwhite, rgb(214,214,214))
```

Is there a way to get alternating colours even after suppressing some records?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the formula {@SuppressSection?} holds your suppression logic, I would suggest using the following color formula:

```
booleanvar alternate;
if not({@SuppressSection?}) then alternate:=not(alternate);
if alternate then crWhite else color(214,214,214)
```

This will ignore suppressed sections and only alternate the color for displayed records.