# In a group footer, how to get alternating background colour for records in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

This is related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21533007/how-to-get-alternating-background-colour-for-records-in-crystal-reports), but I want the alternating background color in a group footer.  My detail section is suppressed for my subreport, and the grouping gives me a grand total at the end.

So, my suppressed detail has something like this (except I have about a dozen plus types instead of two):

```
TypeA  100
TypeA   50
TypeB   50
TypeB   30
TypeB   20
Typec  150
```

And my group footer has the pretty totals

```
TypeA  150
TypeB  100
TypeC  150
```

I want the color to turn on and off in the group footer.  If I were in the details, I'd use the formula in the color for the section:

```
IF RecordNumber MOD 2 = 1 THEN
   crNoColor
ELSE
   Color (234,234,234);
```

But if I do that in the group footer, the RecordNumber might be even several times in a row, then odd, and so I'll get several lines white, then a grey one, then a couple more white.

I've been trying to make a variable that is set to 1 on the first record and increments by one each on each time the group changes.  Then I could treat it in the color section like the RecordNumber.  So far I've succeeded in making a variable that won't change at all, let alone getting anything to work in the color tab.

What is a good way to make the group footer records have an alternating background color?

Comment: There's another system variable - `GroupNumber`. If you have simple aggregation scheme, not nested groups, then this number can be used exatly like you used `RecordNumber`.

Comment: @Arvo - if you make that an answer, I will accept it.  The answer by Siva would probably work too, but not making a variable is a cleaner option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's another system variable - `GroupNumber`. If you have simple aggregation scheme, not nested groups, then this number can be used exactly like you used `RecordNumber`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are resetting the variable so it is not changing.. Don't reset it follow the below process.

In group footer create a formula `@counter` and write below code

```
Shared NumberVar counter;

counter:=counter+1
```

Now in section expert of the group footer go to color tab and write below code:

```
shared numbervar counter;

if counter mod 2=0
then crMaroon
else crBlue
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a Running total example #shade 
[#shade screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0acSk.png)

Put this running total in the GroupFooter you want shown on your report (you should have a distinct record to count) now it should have a 1-through however many records are in your GF, then this can be suppressed. 
Next create a formula called `EvenOdd`, and use this formula:

```
If remainder({#shade},2) = 0 then "Even" else "odd"
```

Drop that formula on your GF and suppress.

Next go to your selection expert, pick your GF, then `Color` tab, select `x-2` and use this formula:

```
If {@EvenOdd}= "Even" then crWhite else crSilver
```

This will now show your GF every other line first silver then white.
You can choose many color schemes

I have done this as sometimes you may want the details of a report suppressed and only showing a Group. Hope this helps